# Pygame and Pygame_menu gives Attribute error even though the library exists

Tags: python, pygame-menu

I have a code like the following:

```
import pygame
import pygame_menu

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 1000), pygame.RESIZABLE)
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
menu = pygame_menu.Menu(
    height=400,
    width=600,
    title="Title"
)

for letter in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
    menu.add.label(letter)

menu.mainloop(screen)
```

My pygame_menu and pygame are the newest version, just installed them both about an hour ago, I cannot figure out why it keeps giving me:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Yun Fei\Desktop\SFU\CMPT 403\Assignment 2\unencrypt.py", line 14, in 
menu.add_label(letter)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Menu' object has no attribute 'add_label'

Edit:
The error has been fixed after I changed the code, however now it just shows a black screen after which it freezes?

Comment: it should be `menu.add.label`

Comment: @Pignotto I fixed the error but now it shows a black screen and then crashes why?

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine for me, showing a menu with 26 labels as expected. Which versions of python, pygame and pygame_menu are you using?